# How to change the position of a button?

Tags: html, css

I have a question. I wanted to use a button from codepen.io on my website (this one: https://codepen.io/emared/pen/RYgbaJ/). Everything works with the button but it appears on the end of my website. I want it to be just below my text. Here's my code:

```
<h3 style="padding-top: 35;">
    Text</h3>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="my-super-cool-btn">
          <div class="dots-container">
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="dot"></div>
          </div>
          <span>Go!</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

And in my CSS-Document I just pasted everything from the codepen page.

Now this is what it looks like: https://ibb.co/G3cmGdQ

Why's there that huge space between "Text" and the button?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Look at the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900');

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#292929;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}
#wrapper{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.my-super-cool-btn{
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-size:2rem;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.my-super-cool-btn span{
  position:relative;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.my-super-cool-btn span:before{
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:7px solid #F3CF14;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  transition: all .85s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.33, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 30px 85px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 15px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover span:before{
  transform:scale(0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 55px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 15px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dots-container{
  opacity:0;
  animation: intro 1.6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot{
  width:8px;
  height:8px;
  display:block;
  background-color:#F3CF14;
  border-radius:100%;
  position:absolute;
  transition: all .85s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.33, 1);
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot:nth-child(1){
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  transform:rotate(-140deg);
  animation: swag1-out 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity:0;
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot:nth-child(2){
  top:50px;
  right:50px;
  transform:rotate(140deg);
  animation: swag2-out 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity:0;
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot:nth-child(3){
  bottom:50px;
  left:50px;
  transform:rotate(140deg);
  animation: swag3-out 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity:0;
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot:nth-child(4){
  bottom:50px;
  right:50px;
  transform:rotate(-140deg);
  animation: swag4-out 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity:0;
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover .dot:nth-child(1){
  animation: swag1 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover .dot:nth-child(2){
  animation: swag2 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover .dot:nth-child(3){
  animation: swag3 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover .dot:nth-child(4){
  animation: swag4 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes intro {
   0% {
     opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
     opacity:1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag1 {
   0% {
     top:50px;
     left:50px;
     width:8px;
  }
  50% {
    width:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
     top:20px;
     left:20px;
     width:8px;
     opacity:1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag1-out {
   0% {
     top:20px;
     left:20px;
     width:8px;
  }
  50% {
     width:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
     top:50px;
     left:50px;
     width:8px;
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes swag2 {
   0% {
     top:50px;
     right:50px;
     width:8px;
  }
  50% {
    width:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
     top:20px;
     right:20px;
     width:8px;
     opacity:1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag2-out {
   0% {
     top:20px;
     right:20px;
     width:8px;
  }
  50% {
     width:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
     top:50px;
     right:50px;
     width:8px;
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes swag3 {
   0% {
     bottom:50px;
     left:50px;
     width:8px;
  }
  50% {
    width:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
     bottom:20px;
     left:20px;
     width:8px;
     opacity:1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag3-out {
   0% {
     bottom:20px;
     left:20px;
     width:8px;
  }
  50% {
     width:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
     bottom:50px;
     left:50px;
     width:8px;
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes swag4 {
   0% {
     bottom:50px;
     right:50px;
     width:8px;
  }
  50% {
    width:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
     bottom:20px;
     right:20px;
     width:8px;
     opacity:1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag4-out {
   0% {
     bottom:20px;
     right:20px;
     width:8px;
  }
  50% {
     width:30px;
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
     bottom:50px;
     right:50px;
     width:8px;
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="heading">Text goes here</h3>
<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="my-super-cool-btn">
    <div class="dots-container">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
    <span>Go!</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the code below:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #292929;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.my-super-cool-btn {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.my-super-cool-btn span {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.my-super-cool-btn span:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 7px solid #f3cf14;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.33, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 30px 85px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover span:before {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 55px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dots-container {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: intro 1.6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f3cf14;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.25, 1, 0.33, 1);
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot:nth-child(1) {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-140deg);
  animation: swag1-out 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  transform: rotate(140deg);
  animation: swag2-out 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  transform: rotate(140deg);
  animation: swag3-out 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.my-super-cool-btn .dot:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  transform: rotate(-140deg);
  animation: swag4-out 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover .dot:nth-child(1) {
  animation: swag1 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover .dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation: swag2 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover .dot:nth-child(3) {
  animation: swag3 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.my-super-cool-btn:hover .dot:nth-child(4) {
  animation: swag4 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes intro {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag1 {
  0% {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag1-out {
  0% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes swag2 {
  0% {
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag2-out {
  0% {
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes swag3 {
  0% {
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag3-out {
  0% {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes swag4 {
  0% {
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes swag4-out {
  0% {
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 8px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 8px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="title">Text</h3>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="my-super-cool-btn">
        <div class="dots-container">
          <div class="dot"></div>
          <div class="dot"></div>
          <div class="dot"></div>
          <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
        <span>Go!</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. When answering questions, please remember to give a short explanation of your solution and provide any relevant links to documentation or other resources.